# Unexpected token < in JSON when using fetch()

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django

I am trying to connect my React signup page to my Django API so when a user signs up a user profile is created in Django.

I get this error on my console when I try to create a new user:

```
Signup.js:33          POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/profiles/?format=api 400 (Bad Request)
onSubmit @ Signup.js:33
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:188
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:237

VM1121:5 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4
```

This is what I see in network inspector:

```
POST /api/v1/users/profiles/?format=api
HTTP 400 Bad Request
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"
}
```

This is the code I have on signup.js:

```
const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const user = {
        email: email,
        name: name,
        location: 'Example',
        password: password,
        user_id: 1
    };
    console.log(user);
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/profiles/?format=api', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.key) {
                localStorage.clear();
                localStorage.setItem('token',data.key);
                window.location.replace('http://localhost:3000/profile/');
            } else {
                setEmail('');
                setName('');
                setPassword('');
                localStorage.clear();
                setErrors(true);
            }
        });
};
```

and in settings.py:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    "DELETE",
    "GET",
    "OPTIONS",
    "PATCH",
    "POST",
    "PUT",
]
```

I assume I am using the right endpoint. When I run my django server and visit this URL this is what I see:

```
GET /api/v1/users/profiles/?format=api
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "user_id": 1,
        "name": "",
        "location": "",
        "password": "",
        "email": "",
        "signup_confirmation": false
    }
]
```

**UPDATE**

As suggested by one of the answers I tried adding this to my Signup.js

```
   fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/profiles/?format=api')
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(text => console.log(text))
```

This is what I get on my console now

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    

      
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE" />
      

      <title>Profile List – Django REST framework</title>

...
```

Comment: The main problem is "400 Bad Request" when you submit your data.  It means the data being sent is the wrong type or the wrong shape for the endpoint.  It all depends on how your /api/v1/users/profiles endpoint is coded.  Is that a "standard" endpoint that has documentation somewhere or is that home made?

Comment: @James it is home made

Answer (score 0):

As you have provided on network logs, it gives you a "400 Bad Request" you might have to check if you are sending the request to a correct endpoint and whether the requests methods and details have been correctly specified in the fetch call.

This error is a common error and in most cases is caused when the server returns HTML instead of JSON. Since the error specifies it cannot identify "<" which is usually caused due to the html tags being detected upfront.

To fix this error you need to figure out why you're getting HTML (or something else) instead of the JSON you expected. To do this you need to log the data you're trying to parse to the console like shown below.

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/profiles/?format=api')
  .then(res => res.text())          // convert to plain text
  .then(text => console.log(text))  // then log it out
```